# How do I print to an html page from a simple Python Server?

Tags: python, json, websocket

I'm working with this simple Python Server -> https://github.com/opiate/SimpleWebSocketServer. I've written my own version, titled server.py, which is handling requests from an iPhone application. Right now I'm only printing to the console on my EC2/local instance (depending on what i have running), but I can't seem to print to html to display in a browser.

Here is my server code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from SimpleWebSocketServer import WebSocket, SimpleWebSocketServer
import time
import thread
import json


# time benchmarks
startTime = None
startFinishedSendingTime = None
endTime = None


# count of the number of data received; will be 2*n (where n is the number of devices)
# (because each device will send two points over the data socket: raw GPS data and then the calculated result)
dataReceived = 0

# whether we are performing distributed or local calculations
experimentType = ""

# collection of all final calculated results received from the client devices
resultsReceived = []

# used to make sure that we have the same number of connections over control and data sockets
numClientsControl = 0
numClientsData = 0

# a reference to the server (ourself)
server = None

# saveResults -- saves the experiment data to a file
# TODO: implementation
def saveResults():
    global startTime
    global startFinishedSendingTime
    global endTime
    global resultsReceived
    print "--------------------------------------------------------"
    print "-- RESULTS ---------------------------------------------"
    print "--------------------------------------------------------"
    print "Start Time: %s" % startTime
    print "Start Time: %s" % startFinishedSendingTime
    print "End Time:   %s" % endTime
    print "--------------------------------------------------------"
    print "Locations:"
    # loop over all locations
    for data in resultsReceived:
        print data
    print "--------------------------------------------------------"

# reset -- resets startTime, endTime, dataReceived, experimentType, results received
def reset():
    # the number of connected cliends will remain accurate
    # we do not ever reset them
    global experimentType
    global resultsReceived
    global dataReceived
    global startTime
    global endTime
    global server
    experimentType = ""
    resultsReceived = []
    dataReceived = 0
    startTime = None
    endTime = None

    for conn in server.connections.itervalues():
        conn.sendMessage(str("{'command':'RESET'}"))



# not used any more -- GOOD Example code
class SimpleEcho(WebSocket):

    def handleMessage(self):
        if self.data is None:
            self.data = ''

        print self.data
        print self.server.connections
        for conn in self.server.connections.itervalues():
            conn.sendMessage(str(self.data))

    def handleConnected(self):
        print self.address, 'connected'

    def handleClose(self):
        print self.address, 'closed'

# logic for handling the control socket
class ControlSocket(WebSocket):

    # handles an incoming message to the socket
    def handleMessage(self):
        global numClientsControl
        global startTime
        global server

        server = self.server

        if self.data is None:
            self.data = ''

        # get the data in JSON format
        try:
            data = json.loads(str(self.data))
            print data
        except Exception:
            print "Exception"

        # branch based on command
        if data['command'] == 'START':
            # start command received
            # record the current time as the start of the experiment
            startTime = time.time()
            data['numClients'] = numClientsControl
            print "%s Starting Experiment with %s devices" % (startTime, numClientsControl)

            # forward the start message to all devices (including origin device) to signal them to snapshot data and perform their calculations
            for conn in self.server.connections.itervalues():
                conn.sendMessage(str(data))

            # record the time after we've sent all data - we use this to benchmark communication speed
            # TODO: check to see if sendMessage is synchronous or asynchronous (i.e. is it blocking until the data has sent or not; if it isn't blocking, this metric will be flawed)
            startFinishedSendingTime = time.time()

    def handleConnected(self):
        global numClientsControl
        print self.address, "Connected Control"
        numClientsControl += 1

    def handleClose(self):
        global numClientsControl
        global startTime

        print self.address, "Closed Control"
        numClientsControl -= 1

        # deal with disconnect during experiment
        if startTime is not None:
            print "---ERROR---\nClient disconnected (control) mid-experiment\n-----------"
            for conn in self.server.connections.itervalues():
                conn.sendMessage("{\"command\":\"RESET\"}")
            startTime = None

# logic for handling the data socket
class DataSocket(WebSocket):
    def handleMessage(self):
        global dataReceived
        global resultsReceived
        global startTime
        global endTime
        global numClientsData

        if self.data is None:
            self.data = ''

        print "DATA MESSAGE ----------------------"
        print self.data

        # branch based on the data series we are expecting (either raw GPS to be forwarded to other devices or calculated results)
        # out of 2*n messages that will be received, the first n are raw GPS, the second n are calculated results
        if startTime is not None and dataReceived < numClientsData:
            # we are in the first n received messages; forward the data to all other devices
            dataReceived += 1
            print "Have data from %s devices" % dataReceived
            print "Data: %s" % str(self.data)

            # forward message to all devices (except origin device)
            for conn in self.server.connections.itervalues():
                if conn != self:
                    conn.sendMessage(str(self.data))
        elif startTime is not None and dataReceived == numClientsData:
            # we are in the second n received messages; store the results
            resultsReceived.append(self.data)

            if len(resultsReceived) == numClientsData:
                # we have finished collection; save end experiment timing, save, and reset the experiment
                endTime = time.time()
                print "%s Experiment complete" % endTime
                saveResults()
                reset()

    def handleConnected(self):
        global numClientsData
        print self.address, "Connected Data"
        numClientsData += 1

    def handleClose(self):
        global numClientsData
        global startTime
        print self.address, "closed Data"
        numClientsData -= 1

        # deal with disconnect during experiment
        if startTime is not None:
            print "---ERROR---\nClient disconnected (data) mid-experiment\n-----------"
            startTime = None

serverControl = SimpleWebSocketServer('', 9000, ControlSocket)
serverData = SimpleWebSocketServer('', 9001, DataSocket)
# create two threads as follows
try:
    thread.start_new_thread( serverControl.serveforever, () )
except:
    print "Error: unable to start thread"

serverData.serveforever()
```

In addition, I would like to print the parsed JSON objects being generated.

Answer (score 3):

You need to *send* data back; `print` just writes to your terminal.

Use the `self.sendMessage()` to send strings back to the client. See the [*For the Programmers* section](https://github.com/opiate/SimpleWebSocketServer#for-the-programmers) of the README.

> `def sendMessage(buffer)`: send some text or binary data to the client endpoint
>
> - sending a buffer as `str()` will send a text based WebSocket frame otherwise a binary frame